# how to set device discovery state to on through command line in Mobile Emulator

Tags: visual-c++, uwp

I create a `UWP mobile Emulator` through `Microsoft XDE` command like this:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0>XDE.exe /vhd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Emulation\Mobile\10.0.10586.0\flash.vhd" /video "480x854" /memsize 1024 /language 409 /creatediffdisk "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\XDE\10.0.10586.0\dd.480x854.vhd" /fastShutdown

in this way, I create an `emulator`, the emulator is in developer mode, but its Device discovery state is off.
My question is how to set Device discovery state to on through command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know what we can set for the `Emulator`, we can read `XDE.exe`'s usage, to open the help information about `XDE.exe`, you can input in the `CMD` for example like this:
[image]

Now you can see its usage like this:
[image]

There are also details info about each settings in this help file, I did't take the screenshot for the whole file, but as you can see in the usage, there is no settings for the `Device Discovery`.

> My question is how to set Device discovery state to on through command line

So I think you can't set this state through command line, you can only manually set it after your emulator is started. And if you have any special requirements, you can leave a comment under my answer.